# Why can't an object have a list of delegates in ios

Tags: ios, delegates

In iOS, what prevents me from having a list of delegates for an object? I know that you are not *supposed to do it*, but I don't understand if it's just because it doesn't conform to the Delegate pattern or if there is some real technical issues by doing it. I'll explain what I refer to with an example:

Protocol:

```
@protocol MyDelegate <NSObject>

- (void) someMethod;

@end
```

Class Header:

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject

// Correct use of delegate pattern 
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<MyDelegate> delegate;
// Incorrect use of delegate pattern
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray<id<MyDelegate>> delegates;

@end
```

Class implementation:

```
@implementation SomeClass 

// Correct use of delegate pattern
- (void) someMethodThatCallsDelegate {

    ...

    [_delegate someMethod];
}

// Incorrect use of delegate pattern
- (void) someMethodThatCallsDelegate {

    ...

    for(id<MyDelegate> delegate in _delegates) {
        [delegate someMethod];
    }
}

@end
```

In my own projects, I often find myself in a situation where several Objects want to know of some event. Typically in network classes. In these cases, I just use `NSNotificationCenter` instead, but the thought of just having a list of delegates for the object always appeals me (Since I'm also an Android programmer, where a Set of Listeners is completely normal). So, what are the reasons for not having a List of Delegates?

(I also understand that in many cases it's bad design to have more than one delegate for an object, but I'm talking about the cases where it's not, such as in netcode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing to stop you doing this. In fact, this is probably what I use protocols for more than for delegates etc...

However, I'd think about what you call the objects and the protocol.

A `delegate` is some object that your main object "delegates" work to. A table view (for instance) knows it has to have a number of rows, sections, etc... but instead of calculating those itself it says "my delegate is going to do this work for me". It then allows the same tableview to interact with any delegate.

Your objects are obviously not like that as there are many of them. They may all have some common usage though. What is that usage? Is delegate the right word to use?

If they are all "Listeners" then it would make more sense to call the protocol `Listener` with a function `someListenedToActionWasTriggered` and to call the array `listeners`.

Comment: From your answer I just learned that delegation refers more to having some other class do some work for you or deciding something rather than informing that something happened (?). I think you just fixed a hole in my knowledge. Thank you.